# Expression for willing to take on extra work load

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing an application for a job, and i want to express that i am aware of extra hours i have to put in,  willing to do so and probably even happy to.

I now have something like this:

> I am fully aware of the workload which comes with [position] and i am
>   completely willing to put this extra time and energy in it.

English is not my first language, but I feel like there should be a nicer way to write this. Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: When you say "jump" I say "how high?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible alternatives:

- "Committed to meeting the workload"
- "I am enthusiastic to take on the challenges associated with [position]"
- "Flexible with working hours"

Comment: I like "flexible with working hours".